# z-index with CSS animation

Tags: css, animation, z-index

I recently saw a preloading animation on codepen.[link's here](https://codepen.io/hafizfattah/pen/AbBtc?limit=all&page=4&q=loading).

And the keyframe code shows below

```
@-webkit-keyframes kanan {
    0% {-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
    }

    50%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
    }

    100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
    z-index:200;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes kiri {
     0% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
    z-index:200;
    }
    50%{-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
    }
    100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
    }
}
```

I am confused about when z-index of the circles change?I guess z-index changes between keyframes(25% and 75%) so that it has circling effect?Do all the discrete properties behave like that?Thanks in advance.